# Passing queue from external Python script to twisted client

Tags: python, websocket, queue, twisted, autobahn

I already asked the question showing my code, but I will try to explain my problem generically.

I'm implementing an autobahn twisted client and server. I have an external Python too which fills a queue by passing it between multiple threads. I need to pass this queue to the twisted client. Can anybody explain to me how to do that?

Thank you for your help

Comment: You need to pass a queue object to the client? Why not "convert" the queue into a list and send it to the client as JSON? You could always pickle the queue object but that doesn't seem like a good idea to be honest.

Comment: I can make neither heads nor tails of this question.